# Calculating Confidence Interval on a Weighted Average

Tags: confidence-interval, descriptive-statistics, weighted-mean

I'm creating a metric which is a weighted average of a parameter $X_i$. Weights themselves are multiplications of $W_i * T_i$.
In other words, my metric is something like:

$my\_metric = \frac{\sum_i(W_i * T_i * X_i) }{ \sum_j(W_j * T_j)}$

How could I possibly measure a confidence interval for $my\_metric$?

$W_i$, $T_i$, and $X_i$ are all observations with unknown independent distributions.

Comment: How many observations do you have?

Comment: What is the purpose of the weighting, i.e., what is the estimand?

Comment: Let's say around 1500

Comment: Are $W,T,X$ independent of each other?  (actually, the pertinent question is whether the product $W*T$ is independent of $X$.

Comment: It would be an entire speech if I wanna explain my exact estimand but for simplification, let's assume that X_i is a quality inside a word, like char length and T_i is something like the frequency of that word in a vocabulary. And W_i, something like the importance index of that word...

Comment: Most probably yes. They are almost independent. Or at least, let's assume so.